# Escape Html entities ignoring html tags - in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-entities

**BACKGROUND:** I am saving some html in database. That contains html tags and html entities.

**Problem:**
I need to escape HTML entities e.g `<` or `>` without escaping HTML tags e.g `<p>` or `</p>` or `<h1>` or `<br/>` etc. I need solution for escaping HTML entities without escaping HTML tags.

I have used the following code but that escapes HTML tags too.

```
escaped_msg = CGI.escape_html '<p><some message here></p>'
```

I want to get:

```
<p>&lt;some message here&gt;</p>
```

I don't want to escape any HTML tags e.g `<p>` or `</p>` etc

Comment: Do you mean "I want a white-list of tags that don't get escaped"? `<some>` could be construed as a tag.

Comment: I want html tags not escaped at all. By escape I mean html encoded. All other html entities e.g <, >, <<, >>, should be escaped. So if my text has characters like <some text here>, it should be escaped.

Comment: The problem is that `<some text>` is technically valid HTML. You'll need to better define what invalid HTML is.

Comment: Yes you are right. By valid html, I mean standard html tags.

Comment: The trouble is that's a really loose definition, which is why I earlier asked about a white-list of tags you want to preserve as-is.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @GProst @tadman I am using tinymce editor that returns me formatted text including normal html tags, in it. I want to to store that text in my db. When displaying back to the user, the formatting is preserved but any html entity e.g `<some thing>` is treated as html tag by the editor. However, if I escape such entities then they are displayed as such in editor. But then standard html tags are also escaped and  formatting is lost.

Comment: Hmm... tinymce removes `<` and `>` for "invalid" tags itself, why do you need to escape anything? Just store the HTML how a user enters it or how tinymce editor returns it (I mean if you're going to use it with tinymce anyway, right?).
This is a `valid elements` example which you can play with on CodePen, for me it doesn't treat any html entity as tag, only valid ones

Comment: I don't want anything to be removed from text whether it is valid or invalid for tinymce. that is my main issue.

Comment: Well, you have some obvious ambiguity issues.  What if instead of "some message here" you had "a small message here".  That would be `<p><a small message here><p>`...   So is the `a small message here` not HTML?  Because it looks like an <a> tag.

Your best bet is probably a whitelist of HTML tags, but your probably *better* bet is to figure out how your data got into this ambiguous state and if there's some way to get it fixed or get it prior to having it get screwed up like this.